# Set id attribute of element to jstl variable

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

```
<input type = "radio" name = "skillLevel[${status.index}].skillLevelId" id = "skillLevel[${status.index}].skillLevelId" value = "3"/>
```

For input name attribute the value `skillLevel[${status.index}` works fine but for id attribute IDE shows error -

```
Bad value "skillLevel[   ].skillLevelId" for attribute "id" on element "input": An ID must not contain whitespace.
```

**Syntax of id:**
An ID consists of at least one character but must not contain any whitespace.

Is there any way. I just want unique id value for input element as the above statement is within loop. On every iteration I want unique id value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem using jsp:element and jsp:attribute tags. Here is the solution :

```
<jsp:element name="input">
    <jsp:attribute name="type">radio</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="id">skillLevel[${status.index}].skillLevelId</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="name">skillLevel[${status.index}].skillLevelId</jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:attribute name="value">3</jsp:attribute>
</jsp:element>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this id

```
id = "skillLevel${status.index}"
```